# Compute html element's style with css

Tags: html, css, dom

I need to calculate the style of a html element **without** using browser, first I'll grab the page source and download it's css files. how can I compute the style of an html element using it's css files. is there any engine out there to first parse and then compute the style of a given html node with **minimum effort** ?

the following is a good example of css parser but it doesn't give you computed style for a given html node in page source dom tree

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/CSSParser.aspx

Comment: CSS is rather complicated; you need a complete selector engine and inheritance rules and a set of default styles.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

You would pass through the path to your CSS file and it would dump it to a string. Then you could use a variety of string editing functions to find the class you're searching for and pull all the text in the string from { to } and then save that to another string and export it wherever you'd like.

Comment: what about style inheritance and all type of css rules to compute final style on an element, your solution only works for elements with specific class attribute without inheritance.